# Create Sparkline chart in R

Tags: r, rcharts

Is there a way to do something like this in R:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline

I did not find a way to do it in `rCharts`. I would like to use it in a rmarkdown document and it would be nice to have some suggestions.

Comment: `install.packages(sos, dependencies = TRUE); library(sos); findFn("sparkline")`.

Comment: Hi, you can try the htmlwidget `sparkline` : https://github.com/htmlwidgets/sparkline, there is a markdown example !